# Azure API Not Working(sorry for the title I have no idea what's wrong)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-python-sdk

As I said already sorry for the title. I have never worked with Azure API and have no idea what is wrong with the code, as I just copied from the documentation and put in my information.

Here is the code:

```py
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioDataStream, SpeechConfig, SpeechSynthesizer, SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioOutputConfig

speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="ImagineHereAreNumbers", region="westeurope")


speech_config.speech_synthesis_language = "en-US"
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "ChristopherNeural"

audio_config = AudioOutputConfig(filename=r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\SpeechFolder\Azure.wav')

synthesizer = SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
synthesizer.speak_text_async("A simple test to write to a file.")
```

Well as I run this I get no error and in fact, get in my desired folder a .wav file, but this file has 0 bytes and it looks corrupted.

Now here is why I have no idea of what's wrong because if I remove this

```py
speech_config.speech_synthesis_language = "en-US"
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "ChristopherNeural"
```

So it becomes this

```py
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioDataStream, SpeechConfig, SpeechSynthesizer, SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioOutputConfig

speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="ImagineHereAreNumbers", region="westeurope")


audio_config = AudioOutputConfig(filename=r'C:\Users\TheD4\OneDrive\Desktop\SpeechFolder\Azure.wav')

synthesizer = SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
synthesizer.speak_text_async("A simple test to write to a file.")
```

It now works all of the sudden, but with what I assume to be the basic/common voice.

So here is my question: how do I choose a voice that I want(btw is this one "en-US-JennyNeural" style="customerservice" or something among these lines)

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChristopherNeural` is not a valid voice name. The actual name of the voice is `en-US-ChristopherNeural`.

```
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-ChristopherNeural"
```

This is well-documented on the [Language support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#text-to-speech) page of the Speech services documentation.

For other, more fine-grained control over voice characteristics, you'll require the use of SSML as outlined in [`text-to-speech-basics.py`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/includes/how-to/text-to-speech-basics/text-to-speech-basics-python.md#use-ssml-to-customize-speech-characteristics).

Comment: I see, Thank You. Is there a way I can add the "customer server" or "newscast" styles?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the “styles” of a specific voice can be invoked with specially crafted SSML (I even linked an example from the official GitHub repository); is there something that’s unclear?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how to work with SSML, XML. That is why I asked, to know if there is a way to do the same thing without them.

Comment: There is not. Unfortunately, the Python library you’re using doesn’t support many of the functions provided by SSML, including the voice style of the generated speech.

Comment: That's a bummer, is there a tutorial or something like that, that I can use for linking this sort of xml to python, because I have xml code that I got piece by piece from the docs(https://paste.pythondiscord.com/viyinabiku.xml), I just have no idea how to implement it into my python code. Or if you know how please help me.